# json problem (valums ajax uploader with zend framework)

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, zend-framework, mime-types

I am using the [ajax uploader](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/)
and the Zend Framework.

The Problem is when I am using the json response for the onSubmit.
With `$this->getHelper('Json')->sendJson($data);`
I only get a saveas dialog.

The problem is that the uploader expects every responste to be "text/html" but the json helper sends "application/json" as mimetype.

With a usual response every thing works fine, but I need to send some information back to the script.

So how can I say Zend that it should send jsondata with the mimetype "text/html"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can affect the response by using the [response object](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.response.html). From within your controller:

```
$content = Zend_Json::encode(array('Foo' => 'Nice', 'Bar' => 'Vice'));
$this->getResponse()
     ->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
     ->setBody($content)
     ->sendResponse();
exit();
```

Comment: This does not use the sendJson() action helper, but there aren't any options for that method.  Use Zend_Json::encode() to encode your data and send it yourself using this method.

Comment: to output valid json code you have to change your last line to:
`->setBody($content)` and add: `->sendResponse(); exit();` otherwise Zend will surround the json data with your default style

Comment: @axel.klein - I've edited the answer based on your comment. Thanks, and sorry I forgot to include the sendResponse bit, I normally grab the response into a variable before outputting.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another variant

```
echo Zend_Json::encode(array('result' => true));
exit;
```